# Wildcard subdomains on Azure

Tags: azure, dns, subdomain

I'm trying to get an Azure site set up so that it will handle all (wildcard) subdomains, and not require any manual addition of a `CNAME` record every time a new customer signs up and chooses a subdomain like xyz.mysite.com

I'm following this guide:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2015/12/01/mapping-a-wildcard-domain-name-to-an-azure-app-services-web-app-website/

I'm temporarily using a the domain www.joburger.co.za

I've created the `A`, `CNAME` & `TXT` records on the domain (did them all to be sure). In Azure, I've added the hostname www.joburger.co.za and [it works](http://test.joburger.co.za/login?ReturnUrl=%2F).

In Azure, I can also add another hostname for a subdomain, like test.joburger.co.za, and [it works](http://test.joburger.co.za/) too.

But if I don't add a hostname in Azure, then it [doesn't work](http://abc.joburger.co.za/).

How do I get Azure to handle the wildcards without having to manually add the hostnames each time?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your domain manager make sure you have...

- CNAME `*` entry that points to `yourapp.azurewebsites.net`
- CNAME `awverify` entry that points to `awverify.yourapp.azurewebsites.net`

Then in Azure, go to your `App Service` > `Custom Domains` and add a hostname `*.yourdomain.com`. This validates that the hostname is valid and if everything's good you can add the new wild card entry to your hostnames list.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check this if it helps to add wild card domain. 
 https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/azure-websites-and-wildcard-domains/

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, is your question about how you configure your web site to accept wildcard subdomains, or is it about how you configure your DNS service?

If you are using Azure DNS (or any other DNS for that matter), you need to create a wildcard DNS record, `*.joburger.co.za`.  I.e. the record name is '*' and the DNS zone name is `joburger.co.za`.