# How to define exceptions for a wildcarded Azure app service subdomain

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, subdomain, url-routing, custom-domain

I have an Azure app service which has a custom domain configuration with `*.example.com` cname. I want to add another app service for `admin.example.com` subdomain. But all other subdomains should go to the first app. How should I proceed to achieve this? Should I define a new app service as a router which uses `*.example.com`? Are there any better solutions on Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a new app service as a router. In fact, all other subdomains will go to the first app service, only the specific subdomain `admin.example.com` will go to the second app service if there is hostname `admin.example.com` according to your current configuration.

In this case, you have two CNAME records in your DNS domain provider. One is for `*.example.com` subdomain, another is for `admin.example.com` subdomain. A wildcard DNS record is a record that will match requests for **non-existent subdomains**. You can add a wildcard hostname `*.example.com` in the custom domain of the first app service, then it will match all subdomain for that domain `example.com`. When you add it, make sure you have the following records in your domain provider. Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39914184/wildcard-subdomains-on-azure).

- CNAME `*` entry that points to `yourapp.azurewebsites.net`
- CNAME `awverify` entry that points to `awverify.yourapp.azurewebsites.net`

When you have a DNS query. The DNS name `admin.example.com` will be resolved rather than all other subdomain hostnames because **if a separate subdomain is created, it has a higher priority than wildcar**d. Refer to [this](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/597/2237/how-can-i-set-up-a-catchall-wildcard-subdomain).

At last, you can have a [DNS lookup tool](https://dnschecker.org/all-dns-records-of-domain.php) to verify the DNS query result.